# MassTransit : Trying to access MT-* headers for a ConsumeContext<Fault<T>>

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have been trying to use a Fault Consumer to process additional information, but the context for the Fault Consumer doesnt appear to have any of the MT-* headers that I can see in RabbitMq Management Tool when I manually get a message from the error queue there.
Here is the code I was using

FaultConsumer:

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Fault<TestDto>> context)
{
            
    try
        {
            var producingService = context.Message.Host.ProcessName;
                var consumerName = context.Headers.Get<string>("MT-Fault-ConsumerType", "Unknown");
    }
}
```

Consumer:

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TestDto> context)
{
    throw new Exception("Test");
}
```

The only header I can see is MT-Fault-RetryCount (if I enable retries). I was expecting to see all the MT-* headers like MT-Fault-Message and so on. For the most part I can get all the fault details from the context.Message.Exceptions, but was hoping there was a way to grab the consumer name. Is there another way to grab the consumer name, or should it be there in the headers and I'm possibly doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those headers are only added when the message is moved to the *_error* queue. They are not added to the `Fault<T>` produced by the consumer pipeline.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now that I think about it. So there wouldn't be any way to get the name of the consumer that caused the exception in the fault consumer?

Comment: If it isn't in the fault, you could look at the `SourceAddress` of the fault, that would be the endpoint where the consumer faulted.